# How to express modification to the previous pattern in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a series of data like `a, b, c, d, e, f, g,` And I need to transform them into `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'`

So I first select them in visual model, then I did `s/[a-z],/'&'/g`.

But this turns out to transform them into `'a,' 'b,' 'c,' 'd,' 'e,' 'f,' 'g,'`

How could I keep the previous letter and move the comma to the behind of the second single quote?

PS: I need use these comma to target the pattern, as there are other letters without comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below vim search and replace function.

```
:%s/\([a-z]\+\),/'\1',/g
```

`\([a-z]\+\)` captures one or more lowercase alphabets. These characters would be later referenced through back-referencing. `\1` refers to the characters which are present in the group index 1.

*What's wrong with your regex `s/[a-z],/'&'/g`?*

`[a-z],` Matches any lowercase alphabets plus the following comma. `&` in the replacement part will print the whole match. So in our case , the matched characters are replaced by `'` + the match + `'` . And note that your match includes the comma , so you got `'a,'` instead of `'a',`

Comment: what if there is other letters without a suffix comma? this seems can't deal with that situation. I think I missed some important point here in the question. I need these comma to locate the pattern, but want to modify them in the new pattern.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: `a, b, c, d, e, f g` , in here, I don't want to substitue the f g into 'f' and 'g', I want keep them original

Comment: This \(\) thing wrapped the [a-z]\+ as the first part of the pattern and then you retrieve it by \1, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`[a-z],` works, but you are including the comma in the match. You can exclude it with `\ze`.

This substitution works on your sample:

```
:s/\l\ze,/'&'/g
```

- match a lowercase character, `\l`
- end the match, `\ze`
- replace with the match surrounded with single quotes, `'&'`